# Full Text Searching for single characters

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with a TEXT column where the contents is just strings of CSV numbers. Example ",1,76,77,115," Each string can have an arbitrary number of numbers.

I am trying to set up Full Text Indexing so that I can search this column rapidly. This works great. Instead of running queries with

```
where MY_COL LIKE '%,77,%' and MY_COL LIKE '%,115,%'
```

I can do

```
where CONTAINS(MY_COL,'77 and 115')
```

However, when I try to search for a single character it doesn't work.

```
where CONTAINS(MY_COL,'1')
```

But I know that there should be records returned!   I quickly found that I need to edit the Noise file and rebuild the index.   But even after doing that it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with relational databases that way is going to hurt.

Use a proper schema. Either store the values in different rows or use an array datatype for the column.

That will make solving the problem trivial.

Comment: I agree, this is what I would like to do.  This is an 'optimization' of an already normalized schema in order to implement a 'generic' search function...  *bangs head into desk*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem, although I'm not exactly sure what fixed it.

I dropped my table and populated a new one (my program does batch processing) and created a new Full Text Index.  Maybe I wasn't being patient enough to allow the indexing to fully rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  How does 12,15,33 not return that record for a search for 1 with fulltext?  Use an actual table schema to accomplish this.